# On a mobile device using the normal theme, the font used for comments appears bigger than the one used for questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

Using my iPod, questions appear with a font smaller than the one used for comments. (I removed the information about who deleted the question.)

[image: screenshot]

I cannot say if this behavior is constant, or from what depends, as questions that are not deleted could appear normal, as in the following screenshot, or the same as deleted questions, as the next screenshot shows.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

It seems the font is shown smaller in questions that have been down-voted (first and third screenshot), while appears normal in questions with a score higher than −1.

I am not using the mobile theme, as I need to access the moderator tools on *Drupal Answers*.
I am using an iPod running iOS 5.1 (9B176).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font rendering seems to be OK on current mobile devices (iOS7), so I'll assume this has been fixed (or is not necessary to fix).